# No compositing effects on quiting the gtk application

Tags: rust, gtk, compositing, gtk-rs

I want to quit my gtk application automatically after a certain time. How do I properly do this? My issue is, that while the window closes and the program exists, no window effects through compton appearto work, such as fading.

This is my code:

```
extern crate gio;
extern crate gtk;

use gio::prelude::*;
use gtk::prelude::*;

use std::env::args;

fn build_ui(application: &gtk::Application) {
    let window = gtk::ApplicationWindow::new(application);

    window.set_position(gtk::WindowPosition::Center);
    window.set_default_size(350, 70);

    window.connect_destroy_event(move |_, _| {
        println!("Quit main");
        gtk::main_quit();
        Inhibit(false)
    });

    window.show_all();

    gtk::timeout_add(500, move || {
        window.destroy();
        gtk::Continue(false)
    });
}

fn main() {
    let application = gtk::Application::new(Some("example.basic"), Default::default())
        .expect("Initialization failed...");

    application.connect_activate(|app| {
        build_ui(app);
    });

    application.run(&args().collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

`connect_destroy_event` is not even called, since I don't get the print message.